# qml MouseArea for button

Tags: qt4, qml

Does anyone know how to create a button that is linked to Text (number) 
and above its value as long as the button pressed?

i tried this:

`Button { width:100 height:100 text: “up” onPressed: { ++myText.text; } } Text { id:myText text:1 }`

but this increases the value only once.

Comment: your question is not clear.Do you want your button text to keep incrementing as long the button is pressed ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a timer for this job.

```
Item
{
    Button { id:button1 width:100 height:100 text: “up” onPressed: { ++myText.text; } }
    Text { id:myText text:1 } 

    Timer {
     interval: 500; running: button1.pressed ; repeat: true
     onTriggered: ++myText.text
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you set [`Timer.triggeredOnStart`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-timer.html#triggeredOnStart-prop) to true, you don't even need to duplicate the incrementing in the onPressed handler. :)